# SWT TreeCursor Throws IllegalArgumentException upon dispose. Any Workarounds?

Tags: tree, swt, dispose, illegalargumentexception

I'm having a problem with SWT TreeCursor. As the example of this question I will use the "exact" example that is presented in eclipse website for TreeCursor:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet360.java

Now, this example runs and works just fine, but if you so much as click anywhere in the tree, or use arrow keys, thereby making the cursor appear on the screen, upon closing the program, an exception is thrown with this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index out of bounds
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.getItem(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.TreeCursor$3.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.closeWidget(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowShouldClose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at Snippet2.main(Snippet2.java:162)
```

Which has nothing to do with your code. Now as far as I figured out, this is a problem in the SWT library and happens upon disposing the cursor. as it appears from the stack trace, it seems that the Tree Items are disposed prior to disposing the cursor, so when cursor tries to access the TreeItem, an exception occurs. I'm currently using a workaround but I wanted to see if anyone has any idea on how to handle this problem. Any thoughts??!!

PS: I'm on Mac OS X and using SWT 4.2.

Comment: Have you reported this on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: I thought I was using 4.3, while I was using an older version. I updated to 4.3 and the problem went away!! I'll try to reproduce it with the older versions... If it happened, I will report it...

Comment: Yup, it happens in 4.2, but not in 4.3!!! TreeCursor is from 3.8!! That's weird!! Why isn't this reported yet? I guess few people use TreeCursor...

Comment: What was the previous workaround that you used? I'm targeting Luna (4.4) / Mars (4.5) and this is still an issue on OSX. For me it happens when adding objects to an EList which is displayed.

Comment: Wow man, I'm sorry, But I really don't remember what I was doing back then!!